# Problem Downloading Google Calendar Data API Atom XML Sample for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, api, calendar

I am programming for Android using Eclipse Helios.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question or if I'm overlooking something very simple, but I'm having trouble understanding how to download the sample project which is provided for the Google Calendar Data API Atom XML Sample for Android.

The actual code can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/android/CalendarAndroidSample.java?repo=samples

The instructions are in the following link:
http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default

I have setup all the prerequisites (Mercurial, Maven and Android plugins).

I'm confused about the "Checkout Instructions" part and the part in "Setup Project in Eclipse 3.5" which explains how to import the file. I don't know how the project is saved in a local directory.

Once again, I apologize if there is an obvious answer, but I would be very thankful if you could help me out with my problem.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is copied (cloned) in a local directory via the command "hg clone". If you have already downloaded and installed Mercurial, this is as simple as opening a console, navigating to any folder you like and typing:

```
hg clone https://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/ google-api-java-client-samples
```

Once you are done with this, you should be able to follow the instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. It was exactly what I wanted to know.